# Selenium - clicked windows does not open & no error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
#Open Website
    profile_path = r'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ndefault-release'
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
    options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
    service = Service(r'C:\Users\XXX\geckodriver.exe')
    driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)

    # declaration of variables 
    name = "x"
    suffix = "x"
    start_number = 1
    end_number = 1000

        for i in range(start_number, end_number):

            driver.get('https://www.bauhaus.info/gewinnspiel')
            time.sleep(3)
            #driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=f"/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button").click()        
            element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
            element.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            
            driver.switch_to.frame(0)
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=f"/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/div[3]/a").click()

            time.sleep(2)
```

If i add the xpath in the firefox console i get the right output:

> Array [ a.btn.btn-primary ]

But the white windows does not open, only if i click manually on it:

[image]

Comment: Post the correct URL, the URL you posted is not opening the window in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, "usercentrics-root")
if driver.name == 'firefox':
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children', shadow_host)[0]
else:    
    shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root

WebDriverWait(shadow_root, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"))).click()

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title=' blackweekgewinnspiel']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
canvas = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "canvas")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",canvas)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", canvas);
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Two points to note:

1. the Accept Cookies popup is in shadow DOM, for which Chrome + Selenium 4.1 has a ready made solution, but Firefox will also work with Selenium 4 via execute_script.
2. the roulette wheel is in an iframe, so must switch there before clicking.

Comment: Had to switch from firefox to chrome - but then this works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Updated to include an alternative implementation for Firefox.